# Parametric constructor, what is the difference?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

I'm currently reviewing the in general (two) ways to make constructors, both default and parameterized, and I wanted to question what is the difference between these two examples.

Example A:

```
public class dog {

    private String dogName;

    public dog() {
        dogName = "Toby";
    }

    public String getDogName() {
        return dogName;
     }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Dog object = new Dog();
        System.out.println(object.getDogName());
    }
}
```

Example B:

```
public class dog {

    private String dogName;
    public dog (String dogName) {
        this.dogName = dogName;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Dog object = new Dog();
        System.out.println(object.getDogName());
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        Dog object = new Dog("Toby"); 
        System.out.println(object.dogName); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can dynamically construct `Dog` instance with name in 2nd one.

Comment: @Rono this is beyond my understanding, do you have an example of what "dynamically constructing" is?

Comment: Second one gives you more flexibility in the sense you can create different instances of Dog and give them different names where as first one is kind of creating different instances of Dog named Toby.

Comment: Example A - All dogs are named Toby.  Example B - Dogs get the name given to them.  Param constructors mean you can customise some fields on construction. `Dog dog = new Dog("Toby");` Default constructors need customising once the object is created `Dog dog = new Dog();  dog.Name="Toby";`

Answer (score 1):

Example A:

```
public Dog() {
    dogName = "Toby";
}
```

You are hardcoding "Toby" here. So, each time you will instantiate the object of type *Dog*, `dogName` will be initialized to "Toby", as a *default* value, because you have no option to pass the data dynamically during object instantiation with `new` keyword.

---

Example B:

```
public Dog(String dogName) {
    this.dogName = dogName;
}
```

You are dynamically passing the value each time you create the object of type *Dog*. Each time you do so, `dogName` will be initialized to whatever you pass in, as an argument, into constructor.